# Anyone can help with this buffer ovewrflow (ctf) question?

Tags: buffer-overflow, ctf

I am new to bufferoverflow and was told that this code can lead to a buffer overflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define DEFAULT_GAME 0

unsigned int credits;

void game_1();
void game_2();
void set_credits();
void change_game();

void (*games[2]) () = {game_1, game_2};
void (*admin_functionality[2]) () = {change_game, set_credits};
int current_game = 0;

void read_string(unsigned char *buf, unsigned int len){
       unsigned int i = 0;
       char c = 0;

       while (i < len && (c != '\n' || i == 0)){
               c = getchar();
               if (c == EOF){
                       puts("SOMETHING WENT WRONG!");
                       exit(0);
               } else if (c != '\n') {
                       buf[i++] = c;
               }
       }
}

int read_int(){
       int input;

       fflush(stdin);
       if (scanf("%d", &input) != 1) {
               puts("SOMETHING WENT WRONG");
               exit(1);
       }
       return input;
}

int read_int_prompt(const char* prompt){
       printf("%s", prompt);
       return read_int();
}

void
initialize_seed(void) {
       unsigned int seed;
       int fd;

       fd = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);
       if (fd < 0) {
               fprintf(stderr, "Lost my wisdom, I have. Now will I rest, yes, forever sleep.\n");
               exit(1);
       }
       read(fd, &seed, sizeof(unsigned int));
       close(fd);
       srand(seed);
}

void read_flag(){
       unsigned char content[128];
       FILE *file;
       file = fopen("./flag", "r");
       if (file != NULL) {
               fscanf(file, "%s", content);
               fclose(file);
               printf("You seized the opportunity and stole some secrets: %s\n", content);
       } else {
               fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening the file.\n");
               exit(1);
       }
       return;
}


void print_banner(){
       printf("Credits: %d\n", credits);
}

void print_menu(){
   print_banner();

   puts("1) Play");
   puts("2) Administration");
   puts("3) Exit");
}

void set_credits() {
       printf("\n::::::: Set Credits :::::::\n");
       credits = read_int_prompt("(credits) >");
}

void change_game(){
       int opt = 0;
       do{
               opt = read_int_prompt("Select game: (1)Pick a Number or (2)No Match Dealer\n>");
       } while(opt < 3 && opt > 0);

}

void administration() {
       int opt = 0;
       void (*fptr)() = admin_functionality[DEFAULT_GAME];
       unsigned char correct_hash[20] = {
               0x33, 0x54, 0xcd, 0xb5, 0x14, 0x69, 0xa8, 0xfa, 0x4f, 0x9a,
               0x92, 0x53, 0xca, 0x62, 0x90, 0x56, 0xd7, 0xcd, 0xc1, 0x2f
       };

       unsigned char salt[8] = {0x6d, 0x62, 0x67, 0x59, 0x7a, 0x52, 0x72, 0x64};
       unsigned char password[20] = {0};
       unsigned char salted_password[28];

       printf("This is admin functionality.\nPassword: ");
       read_string(password, 54);
       memcpy(salted_password, salt, 8);
       memcpy(salted_password+8, password, 20);
       SHA1(salted_password, strlen((char *)salted_password), password);

       if (memcmp(password, correct_hash, 20) == 0){
               do{
                       opt = read_int_prompt("Select functionality: (1) change game or (2) set credits\n>");
               } while(opt > 2 && opt < 1);

               if (opt-1 != DEFAULT_GAME){
                       fptr = admin_functionality[opt-1];
               }

               fptr();

       } else {
               printf("Authentication failed!\n");
       }
}

void game_2() {
       int i, j;
       int numbers[16];
       int set_credits = -1;
       int match = -1;

       printf("\n::::::: No Match Dealer :::::::\n");
       printf("Wager up to all of your credits.\n");
       printf("The dealer will deal out 16 random numbers between 0 and 99.\n");
       printf("If there are no matches among them, you double your money! (stonks!)\n\n");

       if (credits == 0) {
               printf("You don't have any credits to wager!\n\n");
               return;
       }

       set_credits = read_int_prompt("Wager credits. If you guess the number we roll, you get back the double amount otherwise you lose them\n> ");
       if ((unsigned int)set_credits > credits) {
               printf("You cannot set more credits than you own!\n");
       } else {
               credits = credits - set_credits;
       }

       printf("\t\t::: Dealing out 16 random numbers :::\n");
       for (i=0; i < 16; i++) {
               numbers[i] = rand() % 100; /* pick a number 0 to 99 */
               printf("%2d\t", numbers[i]);
               if (i%8 == 7)  /* Print a line break every 8 numbers. */
               printf("\n");
       }
       for (i=0; i < 15; i++) {  /* Loop looking for matches */
               j = i + 1;
               while (j < 16) {
               if (numbers[i] == numbers[j])
                       match = numbers[i];
               j++;
               }
       }
       if (match != -1) {
               printf("The dealer matched the number %d!\n", match);
               printf("You lose %d credits.\n", set_credits);
               credits -= set_credits;
       } else {
               printf("There were no matches! You win %d credits!\n", set_credits);
               credits += set_credits;
       }
       return;
}


void game_1() {
       int set_credits;
       int guess;
       printf("\n::::::::::: Pick a Number :::::::::::\n");

       if (credits == 0) {
               printf("Thank you for playing. Unfortunately, you lost everything. Bye, see you the next time.\n");
               return;
       }
       printf("Wager credits. If you guess the number we roll, you get back the double amount otherwise you lose them\n");
       set_credits = read_int_prompt("Credits to wager: ");

       if ((unsigned int)set_credits > credits) {
               printf("You cannot set more credits than you own!\n");
       } else {
               credits = credits - set_credits;
       }

       guess = read_int_prompt("Guess a number between 1 and 12 to win the game:\n> ");

       if ((rand() % 12) +1 == guess) {
               printf("You won %d credits\n", set_credits * 2);
               credits = credits + set_credits * 2;
       } else {
               printf("You lost %d credits\n", set_credits);
       }

       }


void play(){
       int opt = 0;

       while(1){
               print_menu();
               opt = read_int_prompt(">> ");

               switch (opt) {
                       case 1:
                               games[current_game]();
                               break;
                       case 2:
                               administration();
                               break;
                       case 3:
                               puts("Pleasure doing business with you!");
                               exit(0);
                               break;
                       default:
                               puts("Invalid option");
               }
       }
}


int main(void) {
       setvbuf(stdout, 0, 2, 0);
   setvbuf(stderr, 0, 2, 0);

       initialize_seed();
       credits = 10;
       play();
       return 0;
}
```

I have found it and it lies in the variable password in administration(). When we supply very long password, the variable of salt,correct_hash,fptr, opt can be overwritten.
The address in administration stack look like this:
ebp-0xc fptr
ebp-0x10 opt
ebp-0x14 correct_hash
....
ebp-0x24 correct_hash
ebp-0x28 salt
ebp-0x2c salt
ebp-0x40 password

We can enter upto 54 characters which mean we can write up to the fptr.
I try to overwrite  all these values so that I can make access to calling fptr() (see call to fptr() in administration()). The overwrite is successful and I have check it with x/40wx $ebp-0x40 ,with the break setting after read_string().

Back to the code, the password is reset after calling SHA1 using the salt and password. and the regenerated password is then compare with the correct_hash value so that we can enter the conditional. Therefore, I got an idea that if we provide our program with our password and salt, we can see the hashed output of the program, and we can just use that as an input for correct_hash part .

However, when i do that, I notice that if my payload contains same password(20char),salt(8char),but with different correcthash(20char). The password we get after calling SHA1 is different. What is the reason behind? Does that mean we cant use this way to exploit the program? ManyThanks.